# setting environment variables to modify package.json for create-react-app

Tags: npm, environment-variables, create-react-app, package.json

I discovered today the use of environment variables in React, and I love it ! Especially using react-router, and filling up the `basename` attribute of the `<BrowserRouter>` component this way :

```
<BrowserRouter basename={`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASENAME}`}>
</BrowserRouter>
```

It's great, but I would like to use the variable `REACT_APP_BASENAME` also in `package.json` file, because as you know, the `"homepage"` line in `package.json` define the `PUBLIC_URL` variable used in `index.html` as `%PUBLIC_URL%`, and I would like this `PUBLIC_URL` to be equal to my `REACT_APP_BASENAME` variable. I think I would need something like that :

`package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "apoc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "%REACT_APP_BASENAME%",
  "dependencies": {....
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By going through some files in node-modules/react-scripts/config, I discovered in the `webpack.config` files that `PUBLIC_URL` is provided to the app as `%PUBLIC_URL%` in HTML files and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.

As the target was to be able to use the same variable also in JavaScript, there is actually no need to repeat the same path in any .env file : just set once the path in `package.json` at `"homepage"` line and you're good to use `PUBLIC_URL` wherever you want, HTML or JS.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an environment variable in your package.json like this.

Cross platform

```
{
  "name": "apoc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "cross-var echo ${REACT_APP_BASENAME}",
  "dependencies": {....
```

Comment: Seems to work, although my terminal is telling me `The project was built assuming it is hosted at cross-var%20echo%20$%7BREACT_APP_BASENAME%7D/.` What do you think ?

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Actually, something I didn't get is that the `homepage` parameter in the `package.json` is the parameter modifying the `%PUBLIC_URL%` in `index.html`, is that right ? Meaning that if I there is no `%PUBLIC_URL%` in `index.html` anymore, the `homepage` parameter is useless, isn't it ?

Comment: On unix systems you can just use "homepage": "echo ${REACT_APP_BASENAME}",

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with React, just answered your question of how to set environment variables to modify package.json.

Comment: Still not working : `The project was built assuming it is hosted at echo%20$%7BREACT_APP_BASENAME%7D/.` and the `%PUBLIC_URL%` is replaced by `echo%20$%7BREACT_APP_BASENAME%7D/`...

Comment: This is normal since you are injecting an environment variable in your package.json

Comment: True, and that's actually the whole point of my question : as I set up env variable somewhere else, i want to keep with DRY principle and not repeat the env variable in the package.json, is it possible ?

Comment: By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json, for example:

  "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath"

Comment: I understand that it's not needed if your index.html is not in a subdirectory.

Comment: The point is that if `index.html` is in a subdirectory and if I need the subdirectory path in `index.html` _and_ in other files (such as some React components), the `homepage` parameter alone is not working because it's only replacing `%PUBLIC_URL%` in `index.html`, therefore I need to implement env variables for the other files. Then comes the question : in order to keep along with the DRY principle, how do you change the `homepage` parameter with an env variable defined in a `.env.production` file ?

Comment: Any solution of this? I am struggling with this one.